# Show diff in file but not allow git to merge them

Tags: git

I want to have, *by default*, some type of files treated as binary but show the diff to the user so they can know what they change.

This is for files that, while a human could understand them, git doesn't really know how to merge them and it can break a project if they are not handled correctly.

Is there any way to obtain this result? I know that I can add in a `.gitconfig` the option:

```
[diff "*.unity"]
  textconv = ps2ascii
  binary = true
```

But the problem is that this doesn't work by default, so the user must assign this configuration to their own system.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a `.gitattributes` file in your repository that contains the following line:

```
*.unity merge=binary
```

or the following:

```
*.unity -merge
```

Both leave your copy in the tree, but leave the branch in a conflicted state during a merge. Run `man gitattributes` to see more information.

If you do have a functional merge driver for these files, you can specify its name instead of `binary`, and then users can configure that merge driver for themselves.